# Google maps api search limit

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to extract lat/lon of restaurants in a given area (center and radius) I am using following query

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=40.7857380,-77.8547540&radius=6000&types=restaurant&sensor=true&key=MyKey

But I can't get more than 20 results at a time? Is this the search limit? Is there any workaround for getting more results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests).  NearbySearch requests return up to 60 results, in groups of 20.  RadarSearch requests return up to 200 results, but with less information.

([Note that RadarSearch is now deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add))